# Mutilple javascript variable iterations with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iteration

i have a form and would like to give users the ability to duplicate a group of fields as many times as necessary. With one group it iterates correctly but when I add a second group the "current" variable iterates collectively instead of being unique to each group... i tried changing all of the "current" to "newFieldset.current" but that returns NAN... any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var current = 0;
    //Add New Fieldset with Button
    var newFieldset = {
        init: function(groupIndex) {
            current++;
            $newPerson= $("#Template"+groupIndex).clone(true);
            $newPerson.children("p").children("label").each(function(i) {
                var $currentElem= $(this);
                $currentElem.attr("for",$currentElem.attr("for")+current);
            });
            $newPerson.children("p").children("input").each(function(i) {
                var $currentElem= $(this);
                $currentElem.attr("name",$currentElem.attr("name")+current);
                $currentElem.attr("value",$currentElem.attr("value")+groupIndex+current);
                $currentElem.attr("id",$currentElem.attr("id")+current);
            });

            $newPerson.appendTo("#mainField"+groupIndex);
            $newPerson.removeClass("hideElement");
        },
        currentID: null,
        obj: null
    };
    $(".addButton").each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var groupIndex = $(this).attr("title");
            //newFieldset.obj = this;
            //var fieldIndex = $(this).attr("class");
            newFieldset.init(groupIndex);
        });
    });

    console.log('r');
});
</script>
<style>
.hideElement {display:none;}
</style>

<form name="demoForm" id="demoForm" method="post" action="#">
<div id="groupCtr1">
    <fieldset id="mainField1">
    <div id="Template1" class="hideElement">
    <p>
        <label for="firstname">Name</label> <em>*</em>
        <input id="firstname" name="firstname" size="25" /> <input id="lastname" name="lastname" size="25" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label> <em>*</em><input id="email" name="email" size="25" />
    </p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>
        <label for="firstname1">Name</label> 
        <em>*</em> <input id="firstname1" name="firstname1" size="25" /> <input id="lastname1" name="lastname1" size="25" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email1">Email</label>  
        <em>*</em><input id="email1" name="email1" size="25" />
    </p>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
    <input type="button" class="addButton" title="1" value="Add Another Person">
    </p>
</div>
<div id="groupCtr2">
    <fieldset id="mainField2">
    <div id="Template2" class="hideElement">
        <p>
            <label for="coname">Company Name</label> <em>*</em>
            <input id="coname" name="coname" size="25" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="codesc">Description</label> <em>*</em><input id="codesc" name="codesc" size="25" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <label for="coname1">Company Name</label> 
            <em>*</em> <input id="coname1" name="coname1" size="25" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="codesc1">Description</label>  
            <em>*</em><input id="codesc1" name="codesc1" size="25" />
        </p>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
    <input type="button" class="addButton" title="2" value="Add Another Company">
    </p>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what server-side language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the value to the element with the jQuery data method. Increment it on click, and then pass it to the newFieldset.init method as the second param. Voila!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Add New Fieldset with Button
    var newFieldset = {
        init: function(groupIndex,current) {
                $newPerson= $("#Template"+groupIndex).clone(true);
                $newPerson.children("p").children("label").each(function(i) {
                        var $currentElem= $(this);
                        $currentElem.attr("for",$currentElem.attr("for")+current);
                });
                $newPerson.children("p").children("input").each(function(i) {
                        var $currentElem= $(this);
                        $currentElem.attr("name",$currentElem.attr("name")+current);
                        $currentElem.attr("value",$currentElem.attr("value")+groupIndex+current);
                        $currentElem.attr("id",$currentElem.attr("id")+current);
                });

                $newPerson.appendTo("#mainField"+groupIndex);
                $newPerson.removeClass("hideElement");
        },
        currentID: null,
        obj: null
    };
    $(".addButton").click(function() {
        var groupIndex = $(this).attr("title");
        var current = $(this).data('current');
        $(this).data('current',++current);
        //newFieldset.obj = this;
        //var fieldIndex = $(this).attr("class");
        newFieldset.init(groupIndex,current);
    }).data('current',0);

    console.log('r');
});
```

Happy jquery-ing to you sir.

Comment: This was like a little bit of heaven. You really saved my life that day :) a little dramatic but I just wanted you to know how much I appreciated it

Comment: I really enjoy helping people. The pleasure was/is all mine. ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you dont make the current variable global it <strike>will</strike> should work. try this:

```
var newFieldset = { 
                  current: 0,
                  init: function() {
                      this.current++; 
                      //rest of init code
                  },
                  //all your other fieldset code here
};
/* all other code */
```

**EDIT:** After re-reading the question, I would take a completely different approach to what you're trying to achieve. The above code will still exhibit the same behavior for you. If the question hasn't been successfully answered I'll do a bigger writeup when i get home.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
...
var currents = {};
var newFieldset = {
    init: function(groupIndex) {
        var current = 0;
        if (currents[groupIndex]) {
            current = currents[groupIndex];
        }
        ++current;
        currents[groupIndex] = current;
...
```